# Display Recent Posts From A Specific Category In WordPress

Tags: wordpress, taxonomy, custom-taxonomy

I can not figure out how to display only specific category posts for the recent posts in wordpress.
I use this code and its works fine but I need to **display only the post from custom (taxonomy) category called "site"**

```
<?php $orig_post = $post;
global $post;
$categories = get_the_category($post->ID);
if ($categories) {
$category_ids = array();
foreach($categories as $individual_category) $category_ids[] = $individual_category->term_id;

$args=array(
'category__in' => $category_ids,
'post__not_in' => array($post->ID),
'posts_per_page'=> 4, // Number of related posts that will be shown.
'ignore_sticky_posts'=>1
);

$my_query = new wp_query( $args );
if( $my_query->have_posts() ) {
echo '<div id="related_posts"><h3>Related Videos</h3><ul>';
while( $my_query->have_posts() ) {
$my_query->the_post();?>

<li><div class="relatedthumb"><a href="<?php the_permalink()?>" rel="bookmark" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?></a></div>
<div class="relatedcontent">
<h3><a href="<?php the_permalink()?>" rel="bookmark" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>

</div>
</li>
<?
}
echo '</ul></div>';
}
}
$post = $orig_post;
wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to fill the $category_ids = array(); with your category id. just check your category id in panel and put it in this arrey like $category_ids = array(25);

Comment: How to display ID from custom taxonomy not one single category?